# Unable to receive spring activemq message

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am trying to configure JMS in Spring with activeMQ, here is my sender code

```
@Service
public class SenderService implements ISenderService{

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory amqConnectionFactory() {
        return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(BROKER_URL);
    }

    @Bean
    public Destination defaultDestination( ) {
        return new ActiveMQQueue(MAILBOX_QUEUE);
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(  ) {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestination(defaultDestination());
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(amqConnectionFactory());
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    public void send(final EmailMessage emailMessage) {
        jmsTemplate().send(new MessageCreator() {

            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                return session.createObjectMessage(emailMessage);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

When I check http://localhost:8161/admin/queues.jsp, I can see a message is incremented in the list, however I am unable to receive this message.

```
@Component
public class MessageConsumer implements MessageListener {

    @JmsListener(destination = ISenderService.MAILBOX_QUEUE)
    public void onMessage(Message arg0) {
        System.out.println("MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM");
    }
}
```

If I create above class and try to deploy war on tomcat7 I see following error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'jmsListenerContainerFactory' is defined
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1168) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:281) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerEndpointRegistrar.resolveContainerFactory(JmsListenerEndpointRegistrar.java:139) ~[spring-jms-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerEndpointRegistrar.registerAllEndpoints(JmsListenerEndpointRegistrar.java:126) ~[spring-jms-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerEndpointRegistrar.afterPropertiesSet(JmsListenerEndpointRegistrar.java:121) ~[spring-jms-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.afterSingletonsInstantiated(JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:185) ~[spring-jms-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5001) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1095) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1930) [catalina.jar:7.0.64]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
```

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-annotated-support).

You have to provide a listener container factory so the framework knows how to wire up each listener container - connection factory etc.

If your app is a [Spring Boot app](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-using-jms-receiving) spring boot will wire one up for you automatically.